# How to delete the last symbol of a word inside an array?

Tags: javascript

I have array with words that end with `*` symbol, i need to delete this symbol. How can I do it if my code to create the array is:

I have tried to do it using reference, but my try doesn't work.

```
let tempArray = this.state.textInput.split(" "); // convert string into array

let filterArray = tempArray.filter(word => word.endsWith("*"));
```

Comment: You could use array's `map` function to replace the asterisk i.e. `let newArray = tempArray.map(word => word.replace('*', ''));`

Comment: if you just want to replace `*` from textInput string: `textInput.replace(/\*/g, '')`

Comment: If all your words end with a `*`, you could try `this.state.textInput.split('* ');`.

Comment: You want to `replace` all `*` or just the ones at the end of the string. Also, please provide some sample data for `textInput`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let tempArray = ["asds*","dseas*","adas"];
let newArray = tempArray.map((word)=>{
if(word.endsWith("*")){
    word = word.slice(0, word.length-1);
}
return word;})
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
tempArray.forEach(function(part, index, theArray) {
  theArray[index] =  theArray[index].replace("*","");
});
```

Comment: What if element having "*" in middle